# Access child model instances in parent model using related_name attribute in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Assuming the following configuration in my models.py,

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   ...fields...

   @property
   def get_trone_heir_name(self):
   TODO: How to access to child models instances and fields?

class MaleChilds(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="male_childs")
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   birthday = models.DateTimeField()

class FemaleChilds(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="female_childs")
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   birthday = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to display Parent heir name, being the males prioritized over females and eldest over the youngest. I'm having difficulties on reaching the child objects in the parent property. How to refer to them? If I write: Parent.male_childs.all() I got the following exception: AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'.

Best regards,

Comment: `self.male_childs.all()` and `self.female_childs.all()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access this with `self.male_childs` and `self.female_childs`.

Since you want to priorize male over female childs, and older ones over younger ones, we thus can obtain the object with:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   ...fields...

   @property
   def get_trone_heir_name(self):
       heir = self.male_childs.order_by('-age').first()
       if heir is None:
           heir = self.female_childs.order_by('-age').first()
       if heir is not None:
           return heir.name
```

So we here first query for the oldest of the male children, if there is no child, we then query for the oldest of the female children. If we found a heir (male or female), we return the name, otherwise, we return `None`.

I think however that the modeling can be improved. Unless `MaleChilds` and `FemaleChilds` have not much in common, or have "different behavior", it might be better to make a single object, and assign `sex` as an attribute to the model. It might even be worth merging this with the parent model, since right now, `MaleChilds` and `FemaleChilds` apparently have no children, and no heir.

Comment: It was a simple example, in really there are five submodels. Would it be possible to assign the same related_name to different submodels since they would have the same field? PS: In this particular case example one could do earliest('birthday') actually.

Comment: @AndréGuerra: no if two `ForeignKey`s point to the same model, you can not use the same `related_name`, since then it is no longer clear which one to take.